# mean()-function "loses" _time

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

in the question [Take the median of a grouped set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489205/take-the-median-of-a-grouped-set/74489818#74489818) I asked how it's possible to get the `mean()` value of a set of measurements over time.

Background:

I am storing lighthouse-data. Each lighthouse-run is a `measuring_point` and belongs to a `measurement`. Each `measurement` has its own unique uuid.

So the structure does look like this:

- site

  - measurement

    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
  - measurement

    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
- site

  - measurement

    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
  - measurement

    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point
    - measurement_point

For each measurement_point I am getting the mean()-value as explained here:
[Take the median of a grouped set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489205/take-the-median-of-a-grouped-set/74489818#74489818)

```
from(bucket: "test")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "lighthouse")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "speedindex")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["site"] == "1d1a13a3-bb07-3447-a3b7-d8ffcae74045")
  |> group(columns: ["measurement"])
  |> mean()
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

Now I saw that if I do that, the records ore "losing" their `_time`, which leads to this graph:

[image]

As you can see: Although the measurements have not been performed at the same time, the values are "stacked" at the same time.

If I render a simple table, I am getting this result:

[image]

This is fine, but I guess it shows the problem: The mean() value is calculated but there is no thing as a "mean time". And even if I choose `median`, which should pick the median value (which would have a time, I guess) the `_time`-value is missing.

What can I do to get the time back?

Comment: Technically, median could have a time (it doesn't), but do you really need it? All these functions do some aggregation over a period, and for most the same aggregation make no sense to be applied to time. You can identify the period either by start or stop time. `aggregateWindow` function by default fills `_time` with stop time (see `timeSrc` and `timeDst` params) by simply calling `|> duplicate(column: timeSrc, as: timeDst)`, .ie `|> duplicate(column: "_stop", as: "_time")`

Comment: Hi, hm, I don't know if I get you correctly. Why doesn't it make sense to be applied on time? What I want to get: For each measurement (contains 3 values) the one "in the middle". And as I possibly get thousands of measurements, I want to graph the results later and to do that I'd need the time for the x-axis? So I guess I don't really get what you mean, but maybe this can help to clarify my question.

Comment: You only have `_start` and `_stop` time (marking the aggregation time window) available that you can chose as time for x-axis.